# What is a good resource for walks in the Peak District?

Tags: online-resources, walking, england, peak-district

Is there a comprehensive or "best of" resource (website, book, other) that provides information on walks in the Peak District, including maps, locations, length, ease, sites of interest, etc?

I've mainly found websites that have a smattering of different walks but nothing that provides an overall and useful database of them.

Comment: The Peak District is quite large, and has a huge number of possible walks (combining the paths in different ways), so for a comprehensive set you might be best off just learning to read OS maps and make your own!

Comment: See also [Outdoors.SE].

Comment: @Gagravarr Good point, I've updated it for comprehensive _or_ something similar to a "best of" list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Walking Britain](http://www.walkingbritain.co.uk/walks/select_walk.php) has a great collection of walks, including many in the Peak District.  It has information on grading/difficulty, length, locations, detailed instructions, and items of interest along the way.  It does not have detailed maps, but provides references to the relevant OS maps that should be taken along.